# NoMethodError in Messages#index, error with form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, form-for

I've found multiple solutions to this problem, but none of them seem to work for me. In my messages/index.html.erb, I've put:

```
<%= form_for(@message, :remote => true) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :content %>
<%= f.submit "Send" %>
<% end %>
```

and in my MessagesController:

```
  def index
    @message = Message.new
    @messages = Message.all
  end
```

and in my routes.rb:

```
get "/messages/index"
```

but for some reason I'm getting the error:

```
NoMethodError in Messages#index
undefined method `messages_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000010207d7c8>:0x0000010205c6b8>

Extracted source (around line #5):

2:  <%= render @messages %>
3: </ul>
4: 
5: <%= form_for(@message, :remote => true) do |f| %>
6:  <%= f.text_field :content %>
7:  <%= f.submit "Send" %>
8: <% end %>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

form_for, the way you are using it, expects your routes to be set as a resource to a controller.

You should have in your routes

```
resources :messages
```

This will provide you will all the restful URL's

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions